# Can't find Backpack/Crudnews files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-valet

I have a fresh install of laravel (using composer) and Backpack (using composer) and on top of that i installed Crudnews (also using composer) and everything works fine.

But i want to add an "author" column to the Crudnews form so when i started looking for the files (following the documentation) i realise that the only files i have are the migration files. I changed those and migrated and now i have the extra "author" field in my database, so that works. But i can't find the controllers or route files ANYWHERE.

I have looked through all my folders and there are no files that has to do with Crudnews and i'm so confused. They should be there since it works, but i can't find them. But if they arent there the app should break.

Has anyone had similar problems? Or maybe anyone has a solution?

---

PHP: 7.1.14
Valet (Server environment): 2.0.7
System: Mac OS, 10.13.3

Comment: Do you mean [NewsCRUD](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/NewsCRUD) ? If so, on their GitHub page there's a paragraph on how to install `(B) As a package`, listing all files that are replaced. Hope this helps

Comment: @kerbholz I installed it using that exact method and still nothing. I've tried to install it 2 different time and i still don't get any files.

Comment: You mean you don't have for example `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ArticleCrudController.php` after installing NewsCRUD? Take a look at https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/NewsCRUD/tree/master/src/app to see which files are installed, looks like most of the changes you need to make need to be done in those files